# Spark [Scala]: Checking if all the Rows of a smaller DataFrame exists in the bigger DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I got two DataFrames, with the same schema (but +100 columns):

1. Small size: 1000 rows
2. Bigger size: 90000 rows

How to check every Row in 1 exists in 2? What is the "Spark way" of doing this? Should I use `map` and then deal with it at the `Row` level; or I use `join` and then use some sort of comparison with the small size DataFrame?

Comment: If you want a join, just use an innre join, and count the number of rows in `smallDf` and `joinedDf`

Comment: @BlueSheepToken do you mind to post your answer?

Comment: I will, I just thought the except one might be clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `except`, which returns all rows of the first dataset that are not present in the second

```
smaller.except(bigger).isEmpty()
```

Comment: You should avoid the count to check if a dataframe is empty. Except that, I totally agree with the answer !

Comment: Yes, that's true, it seems since 2.4 there's just `isEmpty`

Comment: Strange enough the size of the count is larger than the size of smaller dataframe. That cant be right? Worst case we should have 1000 as a count.

Comment: Maybe this is bigger.except(smaller) ? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with join, probably

[image]

This join will give you all rows that are in small data frame but are missing in large data frame. Then just check if it is zero size or no.

Code:

```
val seq1 = Seq(
  ("A", "abc", 0.1, 0.0, 0),
  ("B", "def", 0.15, 0.5, 0),
  ("C", "ghi", 0.2, 0.2, 1),
  ("D", "jkl", 1.1, 0.1, 0),
  ("E", "mno", 0.1, 0.1, 0)
)

val seq2 = Seq(
  ("A", "abc", "a", "b", "?"),
  ("C", "ghi", "a", "c", "?")
)


val df1 = ss.sparkContext.makeRDD(seq1).toDF("cA", "cB", "cC", "cD", "cE")
val df2 = ss.sparkContext.makeRDD(seq2).toDF("cA", "cB", "cH", "cI", "cJ")


df2.join(df1, df1("cA") === df2("cA"), "leftOuter").show
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| cA| cB| cH| cI| cJ| cA| cB| cC| cD| cE|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  C|ghi|  a|  c|  ?|  C|ghi|0.2|0.2|  1|
|  A|abc|  a|  b|  ?|  A|abc|0.1|0.0|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Would you please also add spark/scala code to your answer? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can inner join the DF and count to check if ther eis a difference.

```
def isIncluded(smallDf: Dataframe, biggerDf: Dataframe): Boolean = {
  val keys = smallDf.columns.toSeq

  val joinedDf = smallDf.join(biggerDf, keys) // You might want to broadcast smallDf for performance issues
  joinedDf.count == smallDf
}
```

However, I think the `except` method is clearer. Not sure about the performances (It might just be a join underneath)